# How to tell a dependent match two nats are equal

Tags: coq, dependent-type

I'm designing a language that uses Parametric Higher Order Abstract Syntax [PHOAS](http://adam.chlipala.net/papers/PhoasICFP08/). In it, I'm using bit vectors from the [bbv library](https://github.com/mit-plv/bbv) which look like `word : nat -> Set`.

Now, in classic PHOAS syntax, I create an internal type for variables, and provide a denotation for that type:

```
Require Import bbv.Word.
Inductive type : Set :=
  | UI : nat -> type.

Definition type_denote (t : type) : Set :=
  match t with
  | UI n => word n
  end.
```

Eventually, I wish to have a simple stack-based notion of state for a language on top of this PHOAS, so I also have "value"s:

```
Inductive value :=
| UI_value n : word n -> value.
Definition state := (nat * (nat -> option value))%type.
```

Converting *from* a value is where I'm stuck. Here's what I want to happen:

```
Fail Definition fromValue_pseudo := (t : type) (v : value)
  : option (type_denote t) :=
  match (t,v) as x return option (type_denote (fst x)) with
  | (UI m1, UI_value m2 n) (* and m1 = m2  *) => Some n
  | (UI m1, UI_value m2 n) (* and m1 <> m2 *) => None
  end.
```

How can I tell the dependent match that if `m1 = m2`, then `Some n` has *both* type `word m1` and `word m2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern-match on `Nat.dec_eq m2 m1` to do case analysis on whether `m1` and `m2` are equal, and in the case where they are equal, pattern-match on the equality proof to "transport" `n : word m2` into `word m1` (below this is done via `eq_rec`).

```
Definition fromValue_pseudo (t : type) (v : value)
  : option (type_denote t) :=
  let '(UI m1) := t in
  let '(UI_value m2 n) := v in
  match Nat.eq_dec m2 m1 with   (* [Nat.eq_rec m1 m2] would require to then flip the equality, or transport a function [word m1 -> word m1] to [word m2 -> word m1], both of which take more typing. *)
  | left e => Some (eq_rec _ word n _ e)
  | right _ => None
  end.
```